# PHP - mixed strings and variables with addition on the var?

Tags: php, string, variables, math, formatting

What am I doning wrong in my formatting for these 2 bits of code?

How can I format the mixture of strings and vars to give me the proper output?

```
$inbody = 60;
$body = "Welcome. For about " . $inbody . "-" . $inbody+15 . " minutes, you'll receive SMS messages." ;
```

Am I allowed to do inline addition like that? or is my only solution to just declare another variable and put it in? like:

```
$addedinbody = $inbody + 15 ;
```

Here is another example IM having trouble with (specifically setting the $body variable):

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$duration; $i++){
$body = $i+1 . "/" . $duration+1 . " " . $task[$newtask];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the addition in the bracket to tell that there is addition.

Like it:

```
$body = "Welcome. For about " . $inbody . "-" . ($inbody+15) . " minutes, you'll receive SMS messages." ;
```

And you problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Like Broken Heart said you need () around the $inbody+15.

Also another tip you dont need to escape out of double quote to insert a variable into a string, but you do in a single quote string.

`$body = "Welcome. For about $inbody -" . $inbody+15 . " minutes, you'll receive SMS messages." ;`

Same as Broken Heart said applies to your for loop.

`for ($i=0; $i<=$duration; $i++){
$body = ($i+1) . "/" . ($duration+1) . " " . $task[$newtask];
}`